# Keras multi-class prediction output is limited to one class

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I constructed a sequential keras model with 35000 input samples and 20 predictors, the test data output classes distribution is :

- Class_0 = 5.6%
- Class_1 = 7.7%
- Class_2 = 35.6%
- Class_3 = 45.7%
- Class_4 = 5.4%

After transforming the outputs into binary class matrix utilizing (np_utils.to_categorical) the training accuracy is around 54%, when i do model fitting with test data (15000 samples), all predictions (100%) happen to be for the same class which is class_3 "highest occurrence in training output", what is the cause of this bias and not having a single prediction for other classes? how to make the model sensitive for predicting fewer classes and improve the accuracy especially if the concurrence in training data is low like  1 - 3%.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(40, input_dim=20,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=500,  verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to rebalance your loss is to:

1. Define a `class_weights` dict:

   ```
   class_weights_dict = {0: 1.0 / 0_class_freq, 1: 1.0 / 1_class_freq, ... }
   ```

   Where `i_class_freq` is a frequency of `i-th` class.
2. Change your `fit` function to:

   ```
   model.fit(X, Y, epochs=500,  verbose=1, class_weight=class_weights_dict)
   ```

The model defined above should be equivalent to your model with Bayessian reweighted classes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve is by over sampling under represented class examples.
i.e., if you have two classes A(66.6%) and B(33.3%), then you sample B twice compared to A.
To make it further simple, you can change your dataset by duplicating B once and making the dataset something like A+2*B.

Or, you can modify your loss function such that it gives more weight when misclassifying the under represented classes.

Comment: vikasreddy, ty for the suggestions. Can you elaborate more on modifying the loss function to give more weight, and for the first part of question, any explanation why the network ignores predicting the rest (54.3%) of other classes in particular class_2  which has a large amount of observations (35%) ??

Comment: One reason I can think of is that the model is not complex enough to minimize the loss function completely, there by it stays at a local minimum which happens to be predicting all the examples to be in class_3.

Comment: As the implementation of weighted loss function refer to https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2115#issuecomment-204060456